# Выражение должно иметь тип класса | структуры

Tags: c++

Необходимо сделать сортировку под дате рождения. Чтоб уменьшить код в 3 раза я засунул цикл в цикл :,), но у меня не получается заменять то, что должно сортироваться

```
    void sorting(NOTE f[]) {
    NOTE temp = {}; //переменная, что необходима для сортировки
    NOTE b;
    for (int a = 0; a != 3; a++) {
        switch (a) {
        case 0: b = f.day;
        case 1: b = f.month;
        case 2: b = f.year;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { //сортировка методом пузырька
            for (int j = 0; j < 7 - i; j++) {
                if (f[j] > f[j + 1]) {
                    temp = f[j];
                    f[j] = f[j + 1];
                    f[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что такое у вас `NOTE`, как без этого что-то говорить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структуру придумал, а синтаксис вы поймёте.

```
// g++ strpoi.cpp -o strpoi
struct NOTE{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

void sorting(NOTE f[]) {
    NOTE temp ; //переменная, что необходима для сортировки
    // внутренний указатель на элемент структуры
    int NOTE::* bp[3] = { &NOTE::year , &NOTE::month , &NOTE::day };
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { //сортировка методом пузырька
          
            // тут маленькая ошибка с индексами
        for (int j = 0; j < 7 - i - 1; j++) {

            for (int a = 0; a != 3; a++) {          
              
                if (f[j].*(bp[a]) > f[j + 1].*(bp[a])) {
                    temp = f[j];
                    f[j] = f[j + 1];
                    f[j + 1] = temp;
                    break;
                }
                if (f[j].*(bp[a]) < f[j + 1].*(bp[a]))
                  break;
            }
        }
    }
}
# include <iostream>
int main(){
  NOTE f[7]={{1,6,12},{2,5,8},{4,4,5},{3,2,7},{1,7,12},{2,6,12},{2,6,8}};
  sorting(f);
  for(int i=0;i<7;++i)
    std::cout<<"{"<<f[i].year<<"/"<<f[i].month<<"/"<<f[i].day<<"}"<<std::endl;
}
```

проверка :

```
> ./strpoi
{5/4/4}
{7/2/3}
{8/5/2}
{8/6/2}
{12/6/1}
{12/6/2}
{12/7/1}
```